# "inaccessible due to its protection level" VS2013

Tags: c#

Recently I'd convert my visual studio 2005 solution file(*.sln) to visual studio 2013 solution file. That was a successful conversion.
And when I started running the code in VS2013. It works fine...

The problem is when I open the MDI Form in designer view, all the menu toolstrips accessibility is changed from public to private.

And I'm getting the following build error

```
"inaccessible due to its protection level"!!!!
```

I encounter the same problem whenever I open the MDI form in designer view.

Can someone help me? I have been trying to fix this problem for the whole day. Maybe there is a very hidden option in the settings of VS2013, which I don't know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay! You are right, it is a bad design. Actually its a 6yrs old project, and I was assigned to add few modules to it. Its hard to implement inheritance or interface at this stage. 

It would be great if you could let me know, what's new in VS2013 that is automatically changing the accessibility of menu toolstrip to private when opening the form in design view?

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the `Modifiers` property on the controls.

You can set it in the Properties Pane:

[image]

You can set it to `Public` if you want to. I do need to tell you this is possibly a bad design so make sure to check that.

Comment: That red arrow is too professionally drawn to upvote this answer. ;)

Comment: @Patrick [Is there a joke about “Freehand Circles” that I'm oblivious to?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138031/is-there-a-joke-about-freehand-circles-that-im-oblivious-to).

Comment: @CodeCaster: Oh right, free hand circles it will be.

Comment: Setting the Modifier to Public will solve my problem. But the very next time when i re-open the Form it automatically changed to private. Am very keen to know what is the secret behind this magic.